# On edit Permission Issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, windows, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am using Laravel on windows and XAMPP. everything was working fine but from past few days whenever i edit any file get following error:

***file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\storage\framework\views/93db7b63a9b0327444fc43e6604864a09a2a3939.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied***

I obliviously googled and tried to clear cache, config cache, view, verified all folders in framework folder. I didn't find any thing wrong but still not able to update any file.

Comment: run `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: No, don't do that. Change the owner of the `storage` directory to that of the web server user.

Comment: i updated the rights of Xampp folder and then it started working. Thanks @KamleshPaul